# How to remove message from a queue after peek?

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I'm getting a batch of messages from a queue, and pick the one I'm looking for, then, how can I move the rest back to queue? or just mark the one I'm needing as not longer available?

```
var receiverClient = new MessageReceiver("ConnectionString", "MyQueue");

// getting a list of 100 
var messageList = await receiverClient.PeekAsync(100);

var myMessage = messageList?.Where(x => x.MessageId == "MessageGuid").FirstOrDefault();
```

after that, I've tried doing something like this:

```
await receiverClient.RenewLockAsync(myMessage);
await receiverClient.CompleteAsync(myMessage.SystemProperties.LockToken);
```

but that use to fail, I think must be related to the fact I'm getting a batch of queues. Any ideas?

The other way I thought was creating another client (one with the ability to send messages) then use `Receive()` instead of `Peek()` but I'll do have 2 clients and I'll do the process a bit slower too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `Receive()` the messages in `Peek-Lock` mode and would call [`Abandon()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.messagereceiver.abandon?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_MessageReceiver_Abandon_System_Guid_) on the messages that you would like to send back to queue and [`Complete()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.messagereceiver.complete?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_MessageReceiver_Complete_System_Guid_) on the messages that you want to be removed from the queue.

Comment: I cannot do the ```Abandon()``` in the unwanted messages, but since I'm setting now the ```Peek-Lock``` you suggested, those keep in the queue, I use just the ```Complete()``` thanks man!